# Formatar data no INSERT e UPDATE Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Bem tenho um gride de cadastro com data, só que eu tenho que utilizar uma mask do *JQuery*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').mask('00.00.0000');  
});
```

Mas quando vou fazer um INSERT, por exemplo, a data 19.11.2016 se transforma em 21.11.2019. Este mesmo caso acontece com o UPDATE.

No caso do UPDATE tentei implementar:

```
DATA = STR_TO_DATE( '$name_01', '%m/%d/%Y' )
```

Sendo que tentei `'%Y.%m.%d'`,`'%Y/%m/%d'`,`'%Y-%m-%d'` entre outras...

No banco de dados está como *date* o campo.
Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: %d.%m.%Y você já tentou?

Comment: @Sorack eita! não acredito que era isso. Deu até vergonha agora ...

Comment: Vou colocar a resposta com uma breve explicação

Comment: Não tem porque ficar com vergonha de errar, o que importa é funcionar. Eu publiquei a resposta, se você puder aceitar apertando no V ao lado dela pra que sirva de referência para alguém com dúvida similar eu lhe agradeço

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está usando `19.11.2016` o formato deve ser `%d.%m.%Y` ficando:

```
DATA = STR_TO_DATE('$name_01', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

O `%d`se refere a dia, o `%m` se refere a mês e o `%Y` se refere a ano, sendo que o `.` é o separador assim como a sua máscara.